# WhenEvent for RecurrenceTable

Tags: difference-equations

[`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) is like [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) for difference equations, but lacks a lot of its bells and whistles.  One thing I'd like to use in [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) is [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html).  Is there an easy way to achieve this?

For example, something like

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[t + 1] == 3 x[t] (1 - x[t]), x[0] == 0.1, 
WhenEvent[x[t] > x[t - 1] && x[t + 1] > x[t], Print["max"]]}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

would detect local maxima, but this is just one potential application among many.

Comment: For the specific example, use [`FindPeaks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) on the output of [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html)

Comment: One way might be to write a function that looks like it does `WhenEvent`, from the outside, but actually just computes the recurrence table and then operates on the output with something like `If[#2 > #1 && #2 > #3, Print[#2]] & @@@ Partition[rt, 3, 1];`. It might get the convenience, but wouldn't actually be doing anything like the same thing (so `StopIntegration` wouldn't happen, although you could just return the output truncated to make it look like it stopped).

Comment: Good thoughts on that example. Any ideas on how to achieve “StopIntegration” or how to change DiscreteVariables?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Nest`/`NestList` and identify yourself, e.g.:

```
r[n_, fu_] := fu[3 # (1 - #) &, 0.1, n]
pos[n_] := 
 Flatten[Position[
   Partition[Sign@Differences[r[n, NestList]], 2, 1], {1, -1}]]
Show[ListPlot[r[10, NestList], Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, 10}], 
 ListPlot[Callout[{#, r[#, Nest]}, Row[{"x[", #, "]=", r[#, Nest]}], 
     Above] & /@ pos[10], PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12]
```

[image]